# Default value not populating in migration with Rails and Postgresql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am currently trying to run this migration:

```
class AddDroppedProjectsCountToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :dropped_projects, :integer, {:default=>0, :required=>true}
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :dropped_projects
  end
end
```

The column is added correctly, but none of the old records are populated with 0.  They are nil.  I have tried using `default=>'0'` as well, to no avail.  Any idea why this might be happening? (Rails 3.0.3)

---

Edited to add: When I create a new user it works fine, and everything looks correct.  It's just the old users that still have nil for that value in the table.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What happens if you say:

```
def self.up
  add_column :users, :dropped_projects, :integer, :null => false, :default => 0
end
```

instead? Without the `:null=>false` you're still allowing `NULL` in `dropped_projects` so there's no reason for PostgreSQL to make them 0. Also, I don't think `:required` is a valid option for [`add_column`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column); since the options are just a simple `Hash` and `add_column` only looks for options it knows about, your stray `:required` option is silently ignored.

Comment: Great Success!  Thanks Mu.  So weird that it takes all that just to fill some 0's.

Comment: @Dave G: Also see my little update about `:required`. The problem with NULL is that sometimes it means "unknown" and sometimes it means "not there", the database has no way of differentiated these two cases; if you don't explicitly say "no NULLs" then the DB can't know if the NULLs are default values or explicit NULLs.

Comment: It worked for me. What if you don't want to force no nulls? Is there another way to do it? What if you don't want to force a default, but just change the values for rows that are already in the database and subject to the migration?

Comment: @B Seven: Just leave the `:null=>false` out but that probably won't do anything to existing rows, you could always `execute "UPDATE table ..."` and do the update half with raw SQL; there's no good reason to be avoid SQL when it is the most direct and efficient way to get the job done.

Answer (score 3):

you could do this:

(taken from http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Migration)

> Using a model after changing its table
>
> Sometimes you’ll want to add a column in a migration and populate it
>   immediately after. In that case, you’ll need to make a call to
>   Base#reset_column_information in order to ensure that the model has
>   the latest column data from after the new column was added. Example:

```
class AddPeopleSalary < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :people, :salary, :integer
    Person.reset_column_information
    Person.all.each do |p|
      p.update_column :salary, SalaryCalculator.compute(p)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What happens if you have a huge collection of existing people on production or so?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to the fact that you are changing the old migration, instead of creating a new. 
In this case, the solution is to check the schema file (**schema.rb**). It does not change automatically, and add

```
t.integer "dropped_projects", default: 0, null: false
```